# UnsatisfiedLinkError when installing APK on Note 4 through ADB

Tags: android, apk, adb, samsung-mobile, samsung-knox

I recently got a new phone the Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (SM-910F) when I use the phone for app development when a install a debug build via Android Studio or ADB or with the gradle build tools. I'm getting the following error when trying to install the app:

```
aegis@test:~/AndroidProjects/ExampleApp$ adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-example-debug.apk 
3194 KB/s (80316404 bytes in 24.555s)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int android.os.Parcel.nativeCreate() (tried Java_android_os_Parcel_nativeCreate and Java_android_os_Parcel_nativeCreate__)
    at android.os.Parcel.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.os.Parcel.init(Parcel.java:2263)
    at android.os.Parcel.<init>(Parcel.java:2255)
    at android.os.Parcel.obtain(Parcel.java:305)
    at android.os.Bundle.<clinit>(Bundle.java:43)
    at android.os.PersonaManager.getKnoxInfo(PersonaManager.java:881)
    at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.<init>(Environment.java:134)
    at android.os.Environment.initForCurrentUser(Environment.java:112)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:106)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:98)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:146)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:90)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
```

I have tried different USB ports and cables on my computer and also different computers and both on windows and linux(Ubuntu) with the same results. This is quite a inconvenience because installing requires me to try it a few times before it actually installs.

Has Anyone have this problem before? and if so fixed it?